# Databinding textColor from variable

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I want to use databinding with variables for colors in xml.
Here is my code:

xml:

```
<data>
    <import type="androidx.core.content.ContextCompat"/>
    <variable
        name="settings"
        type="..censored..Settings" />
</data>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textColor="@{ContextCompat.getColor(context, settings.primaryTextColor)}"
                android:textColorHint="@{ContextCompat.getColor(context, settings.primaryHintColor)}"
                />
```

Settings:

```
data class Settings(val context: Context) {
var primaryTextColor: Int
var primaryHintColor: Int

init {
    primaryTextColor = R.color.defaultText

    primaryHintColor = R.color.defaultHint

}
```

However I'm getting an error

> Cannot find a setter for  that accepts parameter type 'int'

How do I achieve databinding colors with variables?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BindingAdapter` for this.

```
@BindingAdapter("textColor")
fun bindTextColor(textInputEditText: TextInputEditText, textColorResource: Int?) {
    if (textColorResource != null) {
       textInputEditText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(textInputEditText.context, textColorResource))
    }
}

@BindingAdapter("textColorHint")
fun bindTextColor(textInputEditText: TextInputEditText, textColorResource: Int?) {
    if (textColorResource != null) {
       textInputEditText.setHintTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(textInputEditText.context, textColorResource))
    }
}
```

In your XML

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="settings"
        type="..censored..Settings" />
</data>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                app:textColor="@{settings.primaryTextColor}"
                app:textColorHint="@{settings.primaryHintColor}"
                />
```

Comment: where i have to call this bindTextColor function?

Comment: No, you don't have to call the function. You just need to add these line to your `XML` file. `app:textColor="@{settings.primaryTextColor}"
                app:textColorHint="@{settings.primaryHintColor}"`